# DNS Lookup Failure on Terminal Only (Mavericks)

Tags: macos, terminal, network, dns

I recently did a clean install of Mavericks, and ever since I have, I've been having intermittent DNS lookup failures on *the terminal only*.  Browsers work fine (Chrome, Safari).

But nothing works from the command line (`ping`, `tracert`, `curl`, `git clone`, etc.).  The problem will eventually just go away (sometimes 30 seconds, sometimes 10 minutes), and it does help to switch between the network and the guest network (running a 2 year-old Apple Airport Express), but the problem will eventually express on either connection.  It's maddening.

It seems bizarre that the problem is restricted to the terminal; it seems like network requests from the terminal would use the same mechanism as a browser.

- OSX 10.9.4
- Chrome 35
- Safari 7.0.5
- git 1.8.5.2
- curl 7.30.0

Comment: could you share your Terminal commands you use, and if you get error messages ?

Comment: I can do that when I get home.  The commands are all very mundane: `git clone https://github.com/georgepaterson/jquery-videobackground.git`, `ping google.com`.  The error messages are all along the lines of "Unknown host: github.com" or "Couldn't reach google.com".

Comment: I just upgraded to Mavericks and am having this same issue. It's true in other apps like iTerm as well so I assume it's an issue with some core service/library.